# What software was used to produce "The Elements of Typographic Style"?

Tags: typography, book-design

Does anyone know if TeX was used to produce [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Typographic_Style), or if not, what have they used?

Comment: No, it's not done in TeX. In the edition I own (3.2) there is a summary of the software used for each version. The current one was done with InDesign (I think: I'll have to wait until I get home to check).

Comment: @Joseph Wright, you are right, it is InDesign. No need to check :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Joseph and Yan pointed out, the third edition was produced with InDesign.

In my edition (3.1), it says:

> For those concerned about such things, I might record that the first edition of this book was set in Ventura Publisher software, the second edition in Quark, and the third in InDesign. With each such shift has come a marked increase in technical capability. I have still, in every case, been obliged at times to subvert the software, forcing it to do things its makers didn't foresee, or things they did foresee and expressly excluded.

Comment: Yes, I have version 3.2, and it says the same on the Afterword. Thank you.